# Marginalisation - Integrate out a variable

Tags: probability, integration, marginal-probability

I calculated a joint density function of two non uniformly distributed variables.

$$ f_{x,y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot{1 \over \sqrt(x^2+y^2)}$$

I want to "integrate out" one of the variables to get the single variable's PDF. The variables should be located in a circle around the center with a radius of one. I don't get how to define the integral boundaries (if the joint pdf is correct).

The picture below is a histogram that I created numerically.

[image]

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Well, as written, this is not a probability density, *unless* you mean $360°=2\pi$, but then, you should write it like that. The integral boundaries should be obvious, since your density is only different from $0$ for $x^2+y^2\le1$, i.e. $-\sqrt{1-x^2}\le y\le\sqrt{1-x^2}$ (or $-\sqrt{1-y^2}\le x\le\sqrt{1-y^2}$).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It really helped me to find my error! I already tried those boundaries but made a stupid mistake during the calculation (I integrated against y but replaced x on the boundaries). Your comment reassured me to recalculate everything. I also corrected it to $2\pi$.